# Openrowset but select only specific columns from file

Tags: sql, openrowset

Hoping there is a way to do this, I want to use open row set to select only specific columns from a file that has many more than what I need. I'm trying to do the below but getting an error on the FROM clause.

```
 `INSERT INTO TestData ([Column1],[Column2])
    FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\test.xlsx;', 
    'SELECT [Column1],[Column2] FROM [Sheet1$]')`
```

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 50
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Answer (score 2):

It should be this way:

```
INSERT INTO TestData (
[Column1],
[Column2])
SELECT
[Column1],
[Column2]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;Database=C:\test.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```